# Javascript unable to run slide effect of form

Tags: javascript, php, html

Hoping somebody can help me with an issue im having. I cant run my slide function on a drop down form when calling it from another page.

I have an admin.php page which includes a isAdmin.php file to check if the user is an admin user. If not it redirects them to the index.php page. I would then like to call my slide function so that the login form slides down into view but the command isnt working.

Code is..

isAdmin:

```
if(!isAdmin())
          {
                header('Location: ../index.php?status=3'); 
                //Login page should slide down for user to see the status message but function is not working correctly
                echo '<script>  $(document).ready(function (){ $("div#panel").slideDown("slow"); });</script> ';
           }
```

When the login form tab is clicked this is the function that runs (this works fine):

```
$(function() {
    $("#login").click(function(e) {
      //e.preventDefault(); - Stops the page scrolling to the top
      $("div#panel").slideDown("slow");
      $("#toggle a").toggle();
    });
  });
```

Comment: You need the script code on the page your redirecting them to. the redirect is happening, its not even touching the echo statement.

Comment: @mikevoermans so silly! Thank you very much. Working now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(If I understood). Delete `echo` after redirect:

```
 if(!isAdmin()) {
            header('Location: ../index.php?status=3'); 
            //Login page should slide down for user to see the status message but 
            exit;
 }
```

Change `index.php':

```
 <?php if ( (isset($_GET['status']) && ($_GET['status']=='3')):?>
   <script>  $(document).ready(function (){ $("div#panel").slideDown("slow"); });</script> 
 <? endif;?>
```